# What is a "session cookie" and how do I set it?

Tags: java, playframework, session-cookies

I am using Java Play framework 2.3.8. But it seems the set cookie API does not provide a method to allow me to create a "session cookie" (which will last until user closes the browser) with given path and domain.

Does anyone know how to do it? Or is it missing from the Play Java API design?

Answer (score 0):

See [Set-cookie](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Response.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

where transient cookie is session cookie

Answer (score 0):

The session cookie is maintained by Play itself. You can't create it like normal cookies - but you can add or delete entries. The session cookie stores your session data. Since Play is Restful it stores the session data in a cookie in the user's browser.

In Java you can add an entry to the session, a key-value-pair, with
`session("myKey", "myValue");`
and delete one with
`session().remove("myKey");`. Since `session()` is a static method of play.mvc.Controller you can access it from within each controller class that extends play.mvc.Controller.

More information in [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash).